# Can enlarge person affect an eidolon that 's large due to evolution surge?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, summoner, eidolon, stacking

The spell *[evolution surge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/evolution-surge/)* allows a summoner to grant his [eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/summoner-unchained/eidolons-unchained) temporary evolution points that can then be spent so that the eidolon gains the evolution **large**.

An unchained summoner's eidolon can benefit from spells cast by its summoner that normally wouldn't be able to affect it, like the spell [*enlarge person*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/).

Because the evolution large could've been gained naturally, can a temporarily large eidolon then benefit from the spell *enlarge person*?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Why would you specify the greater version when the normal version will grant 4 points which is enough?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I see you have already taken care of it. Yes, that format does suck. I wish that the lowest was first and then progressed in order, clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [*enlarge person*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/),

> Multiple magical effects that increase size do not stack.

But the evolution *Large* is listed as (Ex), making it non-magical. And *greater evolution surge* isn’t increasing the eidolon’s size, the non-magical Large evolution is doing that.

So, rules as written, I agree that *enlarge person*, when applied to an eidolon who already has the Large evolution, should make that eidolon Huge. Whether or not the Large evolution came from *greater evolution surge* is, as far as I can tell, completely irrelevant.

Whether or not I would actually allow that, or any other GM would, I’m less sure. *Enlarge person* has a lot of problems (most importantly that casting time), so I’m not convinced that this is a problem, but eidolons are pretty powerful as it is.

Comment: Good to know that with 3 spells I can become large, huge, and finally gargantuan. Muwhahaha. But yes, I agree that most DM's would say no.